# How to give relationship in node sequalize (Postgre Sql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the Two model Lookup and Organization

```
var Lookups = sequelize.define("lookup", {
    lookup_type: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    lookup_code: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false,primaryKey: true},
    lookup_value: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    sort_order : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER}
});

exports.models = {
    lookups: Lookups
}
```

In this 'lookup' model I used lookup code as primary key

```
 var Organisation = sequelize.define("organisation", {
    name: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    registration_id: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false,unique: true},
    organisation_handle: {type: Sequelize.STRING,unique: true},
    type_code : { type: Sequelize.STRING, references: 'lookups',referencesKey:'lookup_code'},
    address : { type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    area_code : { type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    city : { type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    website : { type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    email : { type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false},
    email_notifications : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,default: true },
    profile_summary : { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    membership_type : { type: Sequelize.ENUM,values:['anyone','allowed_domains','none']},
    allowed_domains : { type: Sequelize.STRING},
    allowed_rating : { type: Sequelize.DOUBLE},
    total_points : { type: Sequelize.DOUBLE },
    published : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,default: false},
    suspended : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,default: false},
    deleted : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,default: false },
    created_by : { type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    created_on : { type: Sequelize.DATE},
    updated_on : {type: Sequelize.DATE}
});

Organisation.hasMany(LookUp.models.lookups)


exports.models = {
    organisation: Organisation
}
```

In 'Organisation' model , i used as primary key reference(foreign key) for typecode . How to give pimary and foreign key relationship .

I am getting error

Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

while saving the organisation data